# Symfony - access related table field from within a form

Tags: symfony-1.4

Is it possible to get a property of a related table of a field within a form? I'm trying to get a property called "getIdentifier" which belongs to the OriginalStone model class.

```
<?php foreach ($form['treatedStones'] as $fields):?>
     <?php $fields['original_stone_id']->renderRow() ?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
<?php foreach ($form['treatedStones'] as $fields):?>
     <?php $fields['original_stone_id']->getObject()->getIdentifier() ?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `treatedStones` is an embedded doctrine form. Try `$form->getEmbeddedForm('treatedStones')->getObject()->getOriginalStone()->getIdentifier()`